# How to use/install @carbon/react in react project

Tags: reactjs, carbon-design-system

I'm creating react project and want use @carbon/react and want to play around with grid component.

as per [https://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?path=/docs/elements-grid--default#overview](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) you can use grid like shown below.(and other components of carbon design system as well)

```
import { Grid, Column } from '@carbon/react';

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <Grid>
      <Column as="article">Example content</Column>
      <Column as="article">Example content</Column>
      <Column as="article">Example content</Column>
      <Column as="article">Example content</Column>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

**Problem:** Not able to install @carbon/react properly and somehow able to install getting many problems with it.

Tried below things.

List of Problems got while installing @carbon/react:

1. npm install @carbon/react. (when react and react-dom version are 18.2.0)
   [image: npm install @carbon/react]
2. npm install @carbon/react. (when react and react-dom version are 17.0.1), now its installed. but ran into node-sass problem (for npm run start).
   [image: node-sass version issue]
3. Then installed node-sass after that below issue occurred for npm run start.
   [image]
4. Got this error too:
   Can't resolve 'react-dom/client' in '/home/abhijeet/ABHIJEET/Demo-Projects/React-Projects/react-carbon-grid/src'

**Expected:** How to use @carbon/react for Grid component. or GitHub repo where I will get the @carbon/react Grid Demo.

Comment: Note: able to install @carbon/react. but not able to do npm run start (getting node-sass & react-dom/client issues)

Answer (score 0):

use `npm install @carbon/react --force` or `npm install @carbon/react --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: able to install @carbon/react. not able to npm run start.

Answer (score 0):

1. [React 18 is not yet supported](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon/issues/11308). You can use `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` flags with npm install to get past this warning.
2. Do not use `node-sass`, it has been deprecated. Install `sass` instead.
3. & 4 should be resolved by #2

If you're wanting to just play around with things, you might find it easier to [use our stackblitz template](https://stackblitz.com/github/carbon-design-system/carbon/tree/main/examples/vite) instead. It provides everything you need to get started.